# Object literal may only specify known properties and 'message' does not exist in type 'ChatMessage[]'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting the error in my chat.services.ts in sendMessage function. 
I am trying to do an async pipe but it's not reading the objects from my chat-message.model.ts

This is my code in **chat-message.model.ts**:

```
export class ChatMessage {
$key?: string;
email?: string;
userName?: string;
message?: string;
timeSent?: Date = new Date();
 }
```

This is also my code in my **chat.services.ts**:

```
sendMessage(msg: string){
const timestamp = this.getTimeStamp();
const email = 'test@example.com';
this.chatMessages = this.getMessage();
this.chatMessages.push({
  message: msg,
  timeSent: timestamp,
  userName: 'test-user',
  email: email });

    getMessage(): AngularFireList<ChatMessage[]> {
    // Query to create  Message Feed Binding
    console.log('Calling getMessages()!')
    return this.db.list('messages')

}
```

I have a feeling this is something obvious, but the code does look fine to me.

I have a feeling it may have something to do with the $key?

Comment: What does `getMessages` look like?

Comment: edited the question, getMessages() is working fine as when I sent a Message prior it came through on my firebase database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my short version of your code, which explains where I would expect to see the error. First, here is a working bit of demo code:

```
export class ChatMessage {
    $key?: string;
    email?: string;
    userName?: string;
    message?: string;
    timeSent?: Date = new Date();
}

const chatMessages: ChatMessage[] = [];

chatMessages.push({
    message: 'Message',
    timeSent: new Date(),
    userName: 'test-user',
    email: 'fenton@example.com'
});
```

The error that you are getting says that:

> 'message' does not exist in type 'ChatMessage[]'

This is interesting... that means it thinks that `chatMessages: ChatMessage[]` looks more like `ChatMessage[][]` (i.e. an array containing arrays of chat messages).

So test the theory by moving the error up to the interesting line with an annotation:

```
this.chatMessages: ChatMessage[] = this.getMessage();
```

I anticipate that this line will have an error, because the type returned by `this.getMessage();` is not `ChatMessage[]`.

If you are still stuck, please give us the `getMessage()` method.